# PHP Validation user exists using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, validation, pdo

I have this form and start by checking if the fields are empty and it works pretty well. My question here is: why do i get errors when I want to verify if user exists? 
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
require_once '../../includes/database.php';
require '../../includes/functions.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $repassword = $_POST['re-password'];
    $conn = connect($config);

    if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($repassword)) {
        $status = 'Fields must not be empty';
    }

    $results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = " . $username);
    foreach($results as $result) {
        print_r($result);
    }
}
include 'staff_create.view.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose username between `'` because is a string.

**But you should use the potential of prepared statements:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->execute($username);
$stmt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

Or

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username");
$stmt->execute(array(":username" => $username));
$stmt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

You will avoid SQL injection writing your querys this way

Comment: It's not even worth mentioning how to "fix" the query by adding quotes. Just use placeholders.

Comment: Thanks! Some people just grab hold of the first thing they see that works, and that's dangerous if it's the version with string interpolation. Nice work showing both forms.

Comment: @user2300408, if the answer was useful,you should mark as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also might to check to see if the username is set...

```
    $username="";
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the else statement and maybe a hard error after the $status is set...

```
<?php 
require_once '../../includes/database.php';
require '../../includes/functions.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $repassword = $_POST['re-password'];
    $conn = connect($config);

    if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($repassword)) {
        $status = 'Fields must not be empty';
    }
    else {
        $results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = " . $username);
        foreach($results as $result) {
            print_r($result);
        }
    }
}
include 'staff_create.view.php';
```

Comment: Reposting the entire thing when it's not obvious what's changed is not helpful. It's best to strip out what's not specifically relevant to your alteration.

Comment: @tadman if you would read carefully, an explanation is before the 'entire thing' about what has changed. Please think of what is helpful to the questioner, not the reader.